# Move files in subdir to another dir

Tags: files, directory

I have a directory : 
`../Music` with **a lot** of music files in **a lot** of subdirectories.

How would i *move* all the files in the subdirectories to another directory ?
Thus, i *only* want to move the files, i don't want to keep the subdirectory structure.

Comment: Similar question from [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com): [How can I move files by type recursively from a directory and its sub-directories to another directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/how-can-i-move-files-by-type-recursively-from-a-directory-and-its-sub-directories)

Comment: @iamsid Aah, i didn't check the unix.stackexchange to be honest, there's some great answers in there too :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the current directory has the subfolders, replace TARGET_DIR in the following statement in use it:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec mv {} TARGET_DIR \;
```

Comment: Nice, i knew it could be done by using find, but my knowledge of the commands in unix is somewhere burried deep inside. Thanks!

Comment: @Aerus you're welcome. And not to sound pretentious, but when you know which command to use, you're only a "man command" away from knowing _how_ to use it.

Comment: Oh, i *knew* i could find all the files in the subdirectories with the `find` command, but i thought i then would just have list of them, which i then needed to process. I forgot about the `exec`, which is basically why i didn't check out the man page for find :) (Of course, if i *would* have checked it out, i would have found out about the `exec` )

Comment: @Aerus Give http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind a read. It'll give you a good idea about what other tasks find can be used for.

Comment: With GNU `find` you can avoid spawning a new `mv` process for each file to move: `find ../Music \( -name \*.mp3 -o -name \*.ogg \) -exec mv -t [TARGET_DIR] -- \{\} +`. Alternatively with POSIX `find`: `find ../Music \( -name \*.mp3 -o -name \*.ogg \) -print0 | xargs -0 -- mv -t [TARGET_DIR] --`.

Comment: i get find: missing argument to `-exec'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 cd ../Music

 for i in `ls -Q`; do  mv $i/* /Path/To/Some/Other/Directory;   done
```

I would suggest to use `cp` instead of `mv` to check whether it is working fine or not. and if it is working fine just delete the `..Music` directory

Edit: added `-Q` (and needed to add this explanation to get beyond six characters)

Comment: I'll see if i can use `cp` (i don't know if i have enough space on my ubuntu partition because i believe it's 150GB+ of music :) ), thanks for the hint!

Comment: Eeek. This is quite wrong actually as it doesn't consider blanks in filenames. I edited in a `-Q` as parameter to the `ls` ...

Comment: Never parse ls output. Use a glob. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#ls

Answer (score 0):

```
(cd ~/Music ; tar cf - ) | (cd /path/to/other/directory; tar xf -)
```

Comment: That's copy, not move.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct, but an easier way to do it, assuming you only have one layer of subdirectories, is:

```sh
mv ../Music/*/*.mp3 [insert target dest here]
```

Comment: This could better be used as a comment.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on others' posts, but yes, perhaps.

Comment: @Virusboy: I think it's a valid answer that hasn't occurred here yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Rhythmbox, banshee, or a similar software. They can scan your music directories.

You can choose to preserve the directory or (in your case) the software can move the files in to a rhythmbox/banshee directory which would eliminate the hierarchy like you wanted.

Then,

```
cp /target/directory/* /desination/directory/ -r
```

Then, delete the original if it was successful.